# NSPredicate with AND in one-to-many relationships

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, subquery, nspredicate

I'm new to NSPredicate so i would appreciate if someone would tell me if i'm on the right way..
The problem: (the classes are sublclasses of NSManagedObject)
I've got a **Player Class** with this field:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *hisNumbers; //it's a set of Numbers
```

The **Numbers Class** is like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * first;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * second;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Season *forSeason; //it's one-to-one relationship with a Season Object
@property (nonatomic, retain) Player *owner; //one-to-one with Player
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * isPresent;
```

The **Season Class** has got these parameters:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *seasonGames; //set of Game
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *numbers; //set of Numbers (inverse of forSeason)
```

What i'm trying to do is a method that takes a *season* object and gives me back all the players of that season...
this is my try:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Player" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
[request setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"nameLast" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY SELF.hisNumbers.isPresent == %@) AND (ANY SELF.hisNumbers IN %@)",[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],season.numbers];
```

but it doesn't work.. the two parts of the query seems to work separately, but maybe it's just a coincidence...

Now it returns every player which has a number with the flag 'isPresent == YES' and another number which is member of 'season.numbers'. What i need, instead, are the players which has got a single 'numbers' that matches both criteria at once...

If you need more details, let me know.. Thanks all

Comment: What exactly is not working? What are you expecting and what are you seeing? I've just tried this out and it seems to work for me. I didn't create classes though, I just used NSManagedObject.

Comment: As Martin R said, it returns every player which has a number with the flag 'isPresent == YES' and another number which is member of 'season.numbers'. What i need, instead, are the players which has got a single 'numbers' that matches both criteria at once... i hope now it's clearer.

Comment: why -1 to my question? because i didn't know the answer?

Comment: +1 good question for a subtle problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your predicate is true for a player which has a number with `isPresent == YES` and a *possibly different* number which is member of `season.numbers`.

To find players which have (at least one) number that matches both criteria, you probably have to use a SUBQUERY (at least I do not know a simpler solution).

Also you can simplify

```
"hisNumbers IN %@", season.numbers
```

to

```
"hisNumbers.forSeason == %@", season
```

This gives the following predicate, which hopefully works for you:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(hisNumbers, $x, $x.isPresent == %@ AND $x.forSeason == %@).@count > 0",
     [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], season]
```

(See [expressionForSubquery:usingIteratorVariable:predicate:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSExpression/expressionForSubquery:usingIteratorVariable:predicate:) in the "NSExpression Class Reference", where a similar problem and the SUBQUERY solution is documented).

Comment: it really seem to work...thank you!! let me do some more testing before accepting your answer... ohh, and thanks for the link... Yesterday i looked for something explaining subqueries, with little success...

Comment: +1 this is one of the rare times where `SUBQUERY` is the correct thing to use.